# Remove data timestamp and get data only every hours python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, time-series

I have a bunch of timestamp data in a csv file like this:

```
2012-01-01 00:00:00, data
2012-01-01 00:01:00, data
2012-01-01 00:02:00, data
      ...
2012-01-01 00:59:00, data
2012-01-01 01:00:00, data
2012-01-01 01:01:00, data
```

I want to delete data every minute and only display every hour in python like the following:

```
2012-01-01 00:00:00, data
2012-01-01 01:00:00, data
2012-01-01 02:00:00, data
```

Could any one help me? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, aribambang, to Stack Overflow. In this forum, it is expected that you will have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it first. Please show the code you have tried here.

Comment: please clarify that what would be result data, you are going to omit data and keep specific one or process on them like sum,averag or..

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use pandas `resample`, here's is an example of how it is used to achieve the output you desire. However, keep in mind that since this is a resampling operation during frequency conversion, you must pass a function on how the other columns will beahve (summing all values corresponding to the new timeframe, calculating an average, calculating the difference, etc...) otherwise you will get returned a `DatetimeIndexResample`. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='40T')
series = pd.Series(range(9),index=index)
print(series)
```

Output:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00    0
2000-01-01 00:40:00    1
2000-01-01 01:20:00    2
2000-01-01 02:00:00    3
2000-01-01 02:40:00    4
2000-01-01 03:20:00    5
2000-01-01 04:00:00    6
2000-01-01 04:40:00    7
2000-01-01 05:20:00    8
```

Applying `resample` hourly **without** passing the aggregation function:

```
print(series.resample('H'))
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndexResampler [freq=<Hour>, axis=0, closed=left, label=left, convention=start, base=0]
```

After passing `.sum()`:

```
print(series.resample('H').sum())
```

Output:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00     1
2000-01-01 01:00:00     2
2000-01-01 02:00:00     7
2000-01-01 03:00:00     5
2000-01-01 04:00:00    13
2000-01-01 05:00:00     8
Freq: H, dtype: int64
```